# Convert case of DynamoDB data types in stream or dump

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

When I dump data from DynamoDB using a data pipeline, it looks like this, with lowercase data types:

```
{"id":{"n":"2918466"},"time":{"n":"1404783111.4180515"},"user":{"s":"46a1dfa6b6b07c72e57fa8c6be657d76cf31b80b"}}
```

but when I stream it with a DynamoDB stream, it looks like this, with uppercase data types:

```
{"id":{"N":"2918466"},"time":{"N":"1404783111.4180515"},"user":{"S":"46a1dfa6b6b07c72e57fa8c6be657d76cf31b80b"}}
```

It's pretty annoying that the output for the stream and the dump aren't identical. I need to read data from both sources in the same HQL queries, so I'm trying to make the case the same. Is there a setting somewhere to change that? Or do I need to parse the JSON and change the case record by record?